# Python package without __init__

Tags: python, built-in

I `pip install`-ed the [flufl.enum](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/flufl.enum) Python package and I noticed that it works despite missing a `flufl/__init__.py` module as regular Python packages. Even stranger is this:

```
>>> import flufl
>>> flufl
<module 'flufl' (built-in)>
```

I tried to reproduce this creating `foo/bar/__init__.py` without `foo/__init__.py` and (predictably) `import foo` fails. How does `flufl` do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the magic is done in the flufl.enum-3.2-py2.7-nspkg.pth file, which is put into site-packages by "pip install":

```
import sys,new,os
p = os.path.join(sys._getframe(1).f_locals['sitedir'], *('flufl',))
ie = os.path.exists(os.path.join(p,'__init__.py'))
m = not ie and sys.modules.setdefault('flufl',new.module('flufl'))
mp = (m or []) and m.__dict__.setdefault('__path__',[])
(p not in mp) and mp.append(p)
```

pth files are evaluated at startup.  In particular, this file creates a new module named "flufl" and puts it into sys.modules.  That also explains why you see it as "built-in":

```
>>> import new
>>> new.module('foo')
<module 'foo' (built-in)>
```

Comment: well, now we know *how*, but *why* would someone make a package like that?

Comment: Flask extensions also do that but set themselves as a type of 'flaskext'. 

I also couldn't find the entire init process for python 2.x documented anywhere. You can get parts of it through the docs for sys, module and site etc.

Comment: The idea of a namespace package is that it can be used between multiple separate distributions. Flask extensions are a great example, each is its own thing on PyPI etc, but they are all under the flaskext.* namespace.

Comment: Btw: sys._getframe is a CPython implementation detail. Relying on this kind of hack is risky. Bottle achieves the same, but in a much more robust way (PEP 302).

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it

```
ls /Users/sbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flufl.enum-3.2-py2.7.egg/flufl/
__init__.py   __init__.pyc  enum/
```

Did you compile flufl.enum together with python ? It's the only way it can be a builtin module.

By the way, I actually read a PEP where packages could skip the init, but I don't remember if it was approved, rejected, or under scrutiny.

Comment: Not the only way — if module object misses `__file__`, it's considered 'builtin', even if that's not true. And by default, module objects do not have `__file__` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

flufl is just a namespace package, declared in the egg's namespace_packages.txt

If you look at its source tree it actually does have `flufl/__init__.py`, but for distribution as an egg it looks like it's not necessary due to setuptools magic.